# Facebook Android SDK - There was a problem generating the Feed story from the provided data

Tags: android, facebook

FB publishing for all my Android applications stopped working today saying - ""There was a problem generating the Feed story from the provided data"". They had been working fine for the last 6 months

All the applications did was publish quotes on users' walls. I use the following code to do this -

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

parameters.putString("attachment", myAttachent);
facebookClient.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters, this);
```

The publishing worked fine till now. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now fixed. It appears to have been a problem with their API service. I have tested and asked my customers to confirm.

They have updated the bug status to "Fixed"

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295765603772094

Comment: It has indeed started working again for all my apps except for a minor change - the cancel button no longer takes it back to my Activity, just reloads the page. But that is a separate bug I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is my working code........currently checked............

```
 try {

                    JSONObject me = new JSONObject(mFacebook.request("me"));
                    fbname = me.getString("name");
                    first_name = me.getString("first_name");

                    System.out.println("Name :: " + fbname);
                    System.out.println("FName :: " + first_name);

                    JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();
                    attachment.put("message", "Oil and Gas Navigator");

                    attachment.put("href", link);
                    attachment.put("description", "<B>" + title + "" + desc);
                    Bundle params = new Bundle();
                    params.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());

                    JSONObject actionLink = new JSONObject();
                    actionLink.put("text", "Link");
                    actionLink.put("href", link);
                    JSONArray jasonarray = new JSONArray().put(actionLink);
                    params.putString("action_links", jasonarray.toString());

                    mFacebook.dialog(mActivity, "stream.publish", params,
                            new SampleDialogListener());

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

@ihurupin I can confirm this issue is affecting ios devices also. Code was working until ~ 24 hours ago (i was debugging specifically adding custom news feed). Now getting a nice "There was a problem generating the Feed story from the provided data"

bug filed with fb dev here [fb dev bug tracking](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295765603772094)